# How can I monitor network in CentOS .5.5 , my application refuse to read sockets

Tags: linux, networking, centos, monitoring

I have weird problem with one of my applications (servers ), its suddenly starts to read socket and before it written back, the connection is closed this is what I see in my logs. Is there any tool in Linux centos that let me see what is happening in this time frame some tools to debug the network ?

Answer (score 0):

Use tcpdump or wireshark. [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) is a common packet analyzer that runs under the command line.  [Wirehark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) is GUI application.

Also you can use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to trace system call.

Answer (score 0):

Along with wireshark and tcpdump, you can also log everything through iptables.  Depending on how your firewall is set up, a log rule would look something like "-A INPUT -j LOG"